# Find the value of $\int_0^2f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying $$f(x)+f(x+1)=x^2+2x+3$$ then find the value of $$\int_0^2f(x)dx$$

I found out that $$f(x)+f(x-1)=x^2-2$$
Using this, we can remove $f(x)$

Also, if I integrate on both sides how'll I calculate the integral of $f(x+1)?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
\displaystyle\int_0^2f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_1^2f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^1f(y+1)\,\mathrm{d}y &\mathrm{where}\;\; y := x-1 \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_0^1f(x)+f(x+1)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_0^1 x^2+2x+3 \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left.\frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2+3x\,\right|_0^1 \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{13}{3}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_0^2f=\int_0^1f+\int_1^2f=\int_0^1f+\int_0^1g=\int_0^1(f+g)$$

Where $g(x)=f(x+1)$.

Can you continue?

MathStackExchangeIsVeryGood, by the way.